# PostgreSQL how to see which queries have run

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a PostgreSQL DB at my computer and I have an application that runs queries on it.

How can I see which queries has run on my DB?

I use a Linux computer and pgadmin.

Comment: any details about what does your application look like and how it accesses database?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Turn on the server log:

```
log_statement = all
```

This will log every call to the database server.

I would not use `log_statement = all` on a production server. Produces huge log files.
[The manual about logging-parameters:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)

> `log_statement` (`enum`)
>
> Controls which SQL statements are logged. Valid values are `none` (off), `ddl`, `mod`, and `all` (all statements). [...]

Resetting the `log_statement` parameter requires a server reload (`SIGHUP`). A restart is *not* necessary. Read [the manual on how to set parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html).

Don't confuse the server log with pgAdmin's log. Two different things!

You can also look at the server log files in pgAdmin, if you have access to the files (may not be the case with a remote server) and set it up correctly. In pgadmin III, have a look at: `Tools -> Server status`. That option was removed in  pgadmin4.

I prefer to read the server log files with `vim` (or any editor / reader of your choice).

Comment: Brandstetter I will just see logs and turn it off. Is it enough just to make log_statement = all? I have opened Server status it asked me something about installing a package but it opened a window and writes: Logs are not available for this server. Should I restart my postgresql?

Comment: @kamaci: I amended my answer with additional information. Follow the links I provided for more.

Answer (score 91):

PostgreSql is very advanced when related to logging techniques

Logs are stored in `Installationfolder/data/pg_log folder`. While log settings are placed in `postgresql.conf` file.

Log format is usually set as `stderr`. But CSV log format is recommended. In order to enable CSV format change in

```
log_destination = 'stderr,csvlog'   
logging_collector = on
```

In order to log all queries, very usefull for new installations, set min. execution time for a query

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

In order to view active Queries on your database, use

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

To log specific queries set query type

```
log_statement = 'all'           # none, ddl, mod, all
```

For more information on Logging queries see [PostgreSql Log](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/05/06/understanding-postgresql-conf-log/).

Answer (score 9):

I found the log file at /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log on a mac installation from brew.

Comment: commamd+shift+. to show hidden files in users folder. .pgadmin ->pgadim4.log

Answer (score 3):

While using **Django** with postgres 10.6, logging was enabled by default, and I was able to simply do:

```
tail -f /var/log/postgresql/*
```

Ubuntu 18.04, django 2+, python3+

Comment: This seems to only log inserts and queries that failed with an error, Helpful answer nontheless.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in pg_log folder if the log configuration is enabled in postgresql.conf with this log directory name.