# High CPU Usage By Postgres Process

Tags: sql, postgresql, codeigniter, cpu-usage

I have an application running on Postgres database, sometimes when I have about 8-10 people working on the application, the CPU usage soars high to something between 99-100%, The application was built on Codeigniter framework which I believe had made provision for closing up connections to the database each and every time it is not needed, What could be solution to this problem. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you

Basically, what the people do on the application is to running insert queries but at a very fast rate, A person could run between 70 - 90 insert queries in a minute.

Comment: This isn't especially surprising if you're running lots of tiny inserts and you have fast storage so the bottleneck is memory/CPU. You're doing lots of work, so there's lots of load. What's the problem?

Answer (score 20):

I came across with the similar kind of issue. The reason was - some transactions were getting stuck and running since long time. Hence CPU utilization got increased to 100%. Following command helped to find out the connections running for the longest time:

```
SELECT max(now() - xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity
                           WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');
```

This command shows the the amount of time a connection has been running. This time should not be greater than an hour. So killing the connection which was running for a long long time or stuck at any point worked for me. I followed [this](https://appychip.com/debug-slowness-high-cpu-utilization-postgresql/) post for monitoring and solving my issue. [Post](https://appychip.com/debug-slowness-high-cpu-utilization-postgresql/) includes lots of useful commands to monitor this situation.

Comment: Hi Ajeet,
In my case, the Maximum Transaction Age is 10 minutes and the CPU consumption is around 95%, any suggestions to analyze the problem?

Answer (score 6):

You need to find out what PostgreSQL is doing. Relevant resources:

- [Monitoring in general](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring.html)
- [Monitoring queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208310/postgresql-how-to-see-which-queries-have-run)
- [Finding slow queries](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logging_Difficult_Queries)

Once you find what the slow or the most common queries are use, [use EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) to make sure they are being executed efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some cases we met that cause high CPU usage of Postgres.

- Incorrect indexes are used in the query

  - **Check the query plan** - Through `EXPLAIN`, we could check the query plan, if the index is used in the query, the `Index Scan` could be found in the query plan result.
  - Solution: add the corresponding index for the query SQL to reduce CPU usage
- Query with `sort` operation

  - **Check `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)`** - If the memory is insufficient to do the sorting operation, the temporary file could be used to do the sorting, and high CPU usage comes up.

    - Note: **DO NOT "EXPLAIN (analyze)"** in a busy production system as it actually executes the query behind the scenes to provide more accurate planner information and its impact is significant
  - Solution: Tune up the `work_mem` and sorting operations

    - Sample: [Tune sorting operations in PostgreSQL with work_mem](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/database/tune-sorting-operations-in-postgresql-with-work_mem/)
- Long-running transactions

  - Find long-running transactions through

    ```
    SELECT  pid
    , now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS duration, query, state
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) >  interval '2 minutes';
    ```
  - Solution:

    - Kill the long-running transaction through `select pg_terminate_backend(pid)`
    - Optimize the transaction or query SQL through corresponding indexes.