# How can I have a live view of queries being executed on Postgres?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm building an application on Node, [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) and [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) and for learning and performance reasons I'd like to see what queries are being executed live on Postgres.

How can I do it? I'm not paricularly interested in a profiler if that means the queries will be stored on log files. I just want to see what is happening right now.

Possible solutions:

- An application like the SQL Server profiler, as long as it displays live queries
- A way to make Bookshelf or Knex to output queries to the console

Unfortunately I searched Google to no avail.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8208376/1216680) ?

Comment: http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/databases/articles/viewing-current-postgresql-queries/

Comment: The libraries you mentioned won't do it, but [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) can do it nicely, via [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see this live information on a tool outside of your application, your best bet is **pgAdmin III**: connect to the server of interest and then select **Tools | Server Status**. This, incidentally, will also show you the server log which is extremely useful when building applications because it gives you immediate access to errors at the PG server.