# How to show last queries in POSTGRES?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is query can I use for show last executed queries in DB PostgreSQL or where (files) can I find this? I use pgADMIN 3

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208310/postgresql-how-to-see-which-queries-have-run

Comment: Use pg_stat_statements. Or set `log_statement = all` and use the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the History tab in the output pane.

You can find or change the location of the file under the `File/Options...` dialog.

Comment: rd_nielsen I want to know all queries (include from remoute pcs) not only me from pgAdmin

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do that.  The best approach may be to establish a discipline wherein all SQL commands are scripted, and scripts are run with a custom script executor that records the time that each statement is executed in a common logfile.

Comment: @rd_nielsen er... `log_statement = 'all'`, or use `pg_stat_statements`

Comment: @CraigRinger: Ah, of course -- that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

For those on the command line using `psql`, you can view the command history with

```
\s
```

Or print it to a file with

```
\s filename
```

See also

- [17 Practical psql Commands That You Don’t Want To Miss](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/psql-commands/)