# How to generate SQL statements dynamically using Doobie (scala)

Tags: scala, doobie

I have the query:

```
val sql = """select
                   id,
                   clientName
             from
                  partnerClients
             where
                  partnerName = ?
          """
```

I read partnerName from excel file and for each I perform the func:

```
case class Partner(name: String)
case class Client(id: Int, name: String)

def queryPartnerClients(partnerName: String) = Query[String, Client](sql, None).toQuery0(partnerName)

def getPartnerClients(partner: Partner): IO[Vector[Client]] =  partnerClients(partner.name)                                             
                                                              .to[Vector]
                                                              .transact(xa)
```

I used this [FAQ](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie-0.2.3/15-FAQ.html) (How do I turn an arbitrary SQL string into a Query/Query0)

The problem is getting empty results when I take partner name from excel, but it works if I specify the same partner name in the code like this for example:

```
def partnerClients(partnerName: String) = {
    val temp = "Partner Name"
    Query[String, Client](sql, None).toQuery0(temp)
}
```

I thought it was the problem with an encoding and I tried to fix it

```
def partnerClients(partnerName: String) = {
    val temp = new String(partner.getBytes("Windows-1251"), "UTF-8")
    Query[String, Client](sql, None).toQuery0(temp)
}
```

But the result is the same - the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208310/postgresql-how-to-see-which-queries-have-run) to turn on logging and found out that parameters sent by me contain whitespaces. Trim function fixed it